# Resisting Arrest: Calling your attorney

Tags: united-states, arrest

If you are detained or arrested by **US** law enforcement and command Siri (handsfree) to call your attorney (obviously do not give the LE a reason to think you are reaching for a weapon).  Can this be charged as resisting arrest?  Any case examples (precedent) are appreciated.

Comment: As a practical matter, you're resisting arrest whenever a police officer says you are, so I would suggest simply waiting to call your lawyer when given an opportunity to.

Comment: Depends very much on the country!

Comment: @Hilmar the part about 'obviously do not give the LE a reason to think you are reaching for a weapon' tells me OP is in the US.

Comment: All the articles I can find on the matter seem to say that obstruction would mean some kind of physical or threat of physical obstruction, but the actual statutes don't define the word so to some extent Ross' comment is spot on if an officer decided that you operating the phone obstructed the arrest because it distracted them or they were worried you were calling someone to come help you.